# How to translate a visual experience to screen reader users

Tags: tables, accessibility, radio-buttons, sorting, screen-reader

I have a table with selectable rows. I can select only one row. Sighted users can click anywhere in a row to select it.

In the context of a website that is as good for blind users and sighted users, should I make a separate table for sighted users and one for blind users ?

This is tricky:

- If a radio is selected, other radio options won't be focusable with TAB key (standard behavior for radio...) how should I handle this ?
- I cannot sort in the column header with a screen reader (or please advise how this could be usable with screen reader)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHjEoz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: "If a radio is selected, other radio options won't be focusable with TAB key (standard behavior for radio...) how should I handle this ?" Could you explain this a little further?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as website exclusively built for the blind or handicapped. In fact by creating a separate website, you are indirectly isolating these people with disabilities and defeats the purpose of web accessibility. A good design/coding should be inclusive and be able to meet everybody's needs.

You cannot "Tab" through the radio buttons (assuming they are grouped correctly with the name attributes) to perform selection. They have to be selected via the up and down arrow keys. Look at your html code again and check if the name in the input field are labelled correctly.

As for sorting, I assumed you going to use JavaScript. You might want to check out this article on [table accessibility](https://www.ssa.gov/accessibility/bpl/bps/tables/basic/default.htm).

Comment: So how can I select a row ?

Comment: For user with disabilities, use the up and down arrow key and tie in with css to select the row. Use pseudo :checked css https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Comment: I mean up and down arrow are nice, but TAB key is a must to go fast. dropping the TAB key is what you advise?